# Dynamically populate values for use with jQuery DataTables & Column Filter

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) and the [Column Filter](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html) plugin.

One of the options in the column filter plugin is to display a dropdown to filter a column's data on.

```
$("#logTable").dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "aLengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 100],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumns": [ 
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": true },
    ]
}).columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
    aoColumns: [ 
        { type: "select", values: ['admin', 'input'] },   /*This creates the dropdown) */
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
    ]
});
```

I'm trying to have that list updated dynamically from the page the data table is on.

I've created a hidden element and gave it the value of the possible options

```
<input type="hidden" id="dValues" value="admin,input">
```

Then changed my script to

```
var dValues = $("#dValues").(val);    
$("#logTable").dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "aLengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 100],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumns": [ 
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": true },
    ]
}).columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
    aoColumns: [ 
        { type: "select", values: [dValues] },   /*No luck */
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
    ]
});
```

I've also tried

```
<input type="hidden" id="dValues" value="admin,input">
```

with no luck. If I remove the `[]` from `{ type: "select", values: [dValues] }` I get each letter of the contents of `dValues` as an option so I think it's possible to get what I want I just can't figure out how to get each item in properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using version DatTables 1.9.  Version 1.10 seems to have added what I needed.  http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html